# Filling array from a data base

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I need to fill an array from a database but must be in this format:

```
$rows = array(         
   array("WD", "80GB","WD800AAJS SATA2 7200rpm 8mb"        ,"$36.90","Y"),
   array("WD","160GB","WD1600AAJS SATA300 8mb 7200rpm"     ,"$39.87","Y"),
   array("WD", "80GB","800jd SATA2 7200rpm 8mb"            ,"$41.90","Y"),
   array("WD","250GB","WD2500AAKS SATA300 16mb 7200rpm"    ,"$49.88","Y"),
   array("WD","320GB","WD3200AAKS SATA300 16mb 7200rpm"    ,"$49.90","Y"),
   array("WD","160GB","1600YS SATA raid 16mb 7200rpm"      ,"$59.90","Y"),
   array("WD","500GB","500gb WD5000AAKS SATA2 16mb 7200rpm","$64.90","Y"),
   array("WD","250GB","2500ys SATA raid 7200rpm 16mb"      ,"$69.90","Y"),
);
```

I am doing it as follows but it does not work

```
$data = array();

foreach ($res as $value) {
    $data[] = array('afiliadios'=>
        array(
            $value[noEmpadronamiento],
            $value[docIdentificacion],
            $value[municipio],
            $value[departamento],
            $value[fechaAfiliacion],
            $value[apellido],
            $value[nombre])
        );
}
```

I want to make a report in pdf, this is the link from where I am leading

http://www.zedwood.com/article/136/generate-pdfs-with-php

Comment: Try to change `$value[noEmpadronamiento]` to `$value['noEmpadronamiento']`. Note quotes.

Comment: I did not notice the single quote, and add it but I do not work

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate the similar array then it should be like this.

```
$data = array();

foreach ($res as $value) {
    $data[] =  array(
            $value['noEmpadronamiento'],
            $value['docIdentificacion'],
            $value['municipio'],
            $value['departamento'],
            $value['fechaAfiliacion'],
            $value['apellido'],
            $value['nombre'])
        );
}
```

Comment: does not show me any errors, generating a PDF but empty and does not show me anything.

Comment: then there is something else that is creating prob. do some cross check like `vardump` or echo exact html before you output.

Comment: code complete

$colw = array(80,80,220,80,40,80,80 );

$data = array();

foreach ($res as $value) {

  $data[] = array(

     $value['noEmpadronamiento'],

     $value['docIdentificacion'],
     $value['municipio'],
     $value['departamento'],
     $value['fechaAfiliacion'],
     $value['apellido'],
     $value['nombre']
   );
}

$total=0;
$curr_x=120;
$curr_y=300;
foreach($data as $r)
{
   $xoffset = $curr_x;
   foreach($r as $i=>$datas)
   {
       $pdf->setColor(0/255,0/255,0/255);
       $pdf->addText( $xoffset, $curr_y , 10, $datas);
       $xoffset+=$colw[$i];
   }
   $curr_y-=20;
}

Comment: I can't execute your code at my end. do some intentional error and then check at your end.

Comment: just for debugging use a static array and print there output in pdf. If it dosen't  work comment your pdf functions or put `exit('test');` and print results line by line. I am sure you will get the error.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\part\reporte_general.php on line 37

which corresponds to the foreach loop through the data returned from the database, the query clarify if it works, print it in another file and returns me the data.

--- foreach ($res as $value) {  -----

Comment: So the problem is in the `$res` variable.

Comment: solve it with WHILE
----------    
while($reg = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
 $data[] = array($reg['noEmpadronamiento'],
            $reg['docIdentificacion'],
            $reg['municipio'],
            $reg['departamento'],
            $reg['fechaAfiliacion'],
            $reg['apellido'],
            $reg['nombre']);
}
-----------------